# How to connect backend writtern in c++ with tcl/tck user interface?

Tags: c++, backend, tcltk

I have seen a header file cpptcl.h . Is it legitimate? Also where can I find a good quick start example for the same. I am using tcl/tk to design user interface and want to call the scripts by forking in c++ code.

Comment: on which operating system? For what kind of application? Please improve your question (probably off-topic on StackOverflow, since not programming related with some [MCVE]) by [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56106449/edit)ing it

Comment: What does "legit" means? I guess it means "legitimate", but then please improve the English of your question. I am not a native English speaker (and `legit` don't even *appear* in my English-French dictionnary)

Comment: Sorry for the bad english I have edited my question. Also I am using Windows operating system and using it to develop an user interface and need to connect to a c++ code by forking.

Comment: My answer does fit for your edited question

Comment: Yes thank you for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to connect back-end written in c++ with tcl/tk user interface?

Your question is [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) specific. Because (on many, but not all, OSes) any software application could be made of two (or more) [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) cooperating by using [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) facilities, and that approach (which is often *implied* by using the "[back-end](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_and_back_ends)" word) has the huge advantage of taking profit from [process isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_isolation). Read more about [software pipelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(software)), about [pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(computing)) and [sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets). They might be available on your target OS.  For a good overview on operating systems, I strongly recommend reading [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) (it is freely downloadable).

If you are coding for Windows, study and learn the [WinAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/apiindex/windows-api-list). If you are coding for Linux, study its programming API by reading [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) and looking into [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and every [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) referenced from that `man` page. Both documentation are useful to code inter-process communications.

You could write a single-[executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) application, by [linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) a [Tcl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcl)/[Tk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tk_(software)) library (or code) with your core, application specific, C++ code, but if you do that, you won't speak of any back-end (or front-end), but of the [application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_software)-specific layer and [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) user-interface [(abstraction) layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_layer) of your code.

At last, Tcl/Tk seems to be out of fashion for GUI development. Today, a good C++ [GUI toolkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_toolkit) is [Qt](https://qt.io/), which is vastly superior (in features and in quality of the look and feel of the interface) to Tcl/Tk.

> I have seen a library cpptcl.h.

That is *not* a [library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)), but a [header file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_directive) (for the C & C++ [preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor)) declaring the interface of some library. I guess that the corresponding library would be a [dynamically-linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) library, e.g. some `lib*.so` 
[ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) shared object on Linux, or some `*.dll` [DLL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library) on Windows.

> Is it legit

I suppose you mean "is it legitimate"? Surely yes. Or "conforming to rules" (then of course yes). You could ask about the legal status of that library, and the right wording for such a question is asking about its [software license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_license). Tcl/Tk are [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) software with some [BSD license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses).

> where can I find a good quick start example for the same.

Both Tk and Qt have *excellent* documentation (that you should *read* during several *days* ...). And the documentation of Tk is impressive (and so is the documentation of Qt). I recommend reading the [Tk tutorial](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/index.html) first (and if you choose Qt, read first its [Getting Started with Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gettingstarted.html) documentation). Most GUI software involve some [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) (which is provided by Qt and probably also by Tk). You probably should have [callbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)) (and Qt uses [signals and slots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signals_and_slots)) from that event loop to C++ functions of your applicative layer.